# Which cluster name is valid DNS name?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to setup Kubernetes cluster on AWS
I have hosted zone created by Route53 Registrar

```
When i try
kops create cluster --zones "eu-central-1a","eu-central-1b" --master-count 3 --master-size=t2.micro --node-count 2 --node-size=t2.micro --name=marinche.markovic-q9.com.
```

markovic-q9.com. is my Hosted Zone

Although I edited my bash_profile

```
export KOPS_CLUSTER_NAME=marinche
export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://kops-state-3107b
```

I got serious issues

```
Name: Invalid value: "marinche.markovic-q9.com.": Cluster Name must be a valid DNS name (e.g. --name=mycluster.myzone.com) errors: a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters..
```

Why?

Comment: Why do you have a trailing dot in the domain name? (This could lead to the assumption that markovic-q9 is already a third level domain). Please try --name=marinche.markovic-q9.com (without the dot at the end)

Comment: My typo,works fine now,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a trailing dot in the domain name, this leads to the assumption that markovic-q9 is already a third level domain. The setup allows only lower case alphanummeric characters in the subdomain.